# Python websocketsを使用したクライアントでのKeep-alive接続方法

Tags: python, websocket

websocketsモジュールを使用して、クライアント側のwebsocketをKeep-aliveで接続したいです。
しかし、時間が経つとサーバーからソケットを切断されてしまいます。
これは、パケットキャプチャした結果、Keep-aliveが送信されていないためにサーバーからFINが返ってきていました。

どのように記述したらKeep-aliveとして実装できるのでしょうか？
クライアント側は完全に待ち受けで、送信はしません。

なお、websocket-clientモジュールを回避しようと思い、websocketsモジュールを使用しております。

```py
import asyncio

import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8080"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:

        while(True):
            ret = await websocket.recv()
            print(ret)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

websocket-clientモジュールを使用した場合に、HTTP:Keep-aliveができ、websocketsモジュールではKeep-aliveができないため、比較として、パケットキャプチャしました。
pyload部分しか違いがありません。画像の左側がwebsocket-clientモジュール使用時のKeep-aliveパケット、右側がwebsocketsモジュールでのping()コマンドでのKeep-aliveを期待したパケットです。

[image: Keep-aliveのパケットキャプチャ]

websocket-clientモジュールのソースコードを見てみると、payloadは空のままping実行されています。(run_forever())
websocketsでは低レベルのpayloadがセットできない。文字列あるいはバイト列で「空」は受け付けてくれません。
根本的にwebsocketsでは無理なのかもしれません。
なお、websocketsのFAQに記載があるpingを20秒間隔で送信するという部分ですが、パケットキャプチャしても、そのような形跡は見当たりませんでした。

Comment: 古そうなものもありますが、何かこれらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Issues listening incoming messages in websocket client on Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49878953/9014308), [Common Client Connection Keep-alive Pattern #581](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/581), [How to keep my receiver of Heartbeat alive using python-websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57863834/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えていただいたいくつかの記事は既読でした。Keep-aliveの代わりに定期的にPingを打ってサーバー側にコネクションを継続させるイレギュラー処理はありますが、サーバー側が不要なメッセージ処理に追われることになります。困りました。

Comment: ping/pongを使うのがプロトコルのようですね。[WebSockets ping/pong, why not TCP keepalive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23238319/9014308), [5.5.2. Ping](https://triple-underscore.github.io/RFC6455-ja.html#section-5.5.2), [WebSocket API仕様(情報受信者向け)](https://doc01.pf.iij-engineering.co.jp/pub/sdkdoc/v1/ja_JP/websocketapi/websockif_pub_receiver.html), [使用するプロトコル](https://doc01.pf.iij-engineering.co.jp/pub/sdkdoc/v1/ja_JP/websocketapi.html#ws-usedprotocol) だからその処理は必要なのでは？

Comment: connection.ping()あるいはpong()を使えば、Keep-aliveと同様にセッションを維持できるようです。リンクの例では、connection.send('ping')と記述され、サーバー側に余計なメッセージが届いてしまっていました。

Comment: ping()/pong()では、Keep-aliveできていませんでした。純粋なKeep-aliveのポーリングができないみたいですね。

Comment: 一応こんなFAQがあるようです。[How do I keep idle connections open?](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=ping_interval#how-do-i-keep-idle-connections-open) あるいはこれとか。[What does ConnectionClosedError: code = 1006 mean?](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-does-connectionclosederror-code-1006-mean) 他に直前に紹介した英語のQ&A記事にはTCP keepaliveとは独立した別の仕組みで実現していると書いてあるようですね。

Comment: その後、keepalive関連はソースコードを検索すると[websockets.legacy.protocol/client/server](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/search?q=keepalive)に書かれていて、通常使う機能では関係無いようでした。そしてping/pong関連は、[websockets/tests/test_connection.py](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/d5cf1efb737a943583b1e5b4ceca5376bdc3995f/tests/test_connection.py)とか[websockets/src/websockets/connection.py](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/d5cf1efb737a943583b1e5b4ceca5376bdc3995f/src/websockets/connection.py)とかを見ると、アプリケーション自身で何とかしなさい、となっている感じでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。Keep-aliveについては、配慮されていないようですね。websocketsも回避するため、asyncioモジュールだけでソケット通信を構築しようとしましたが、writeメソッド自体で空のBytesを受け付けないので、payloadをwebsocket-clientモジュールのように設定することができませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の目的は、WebSocket接続において、相手が送出してくるデータを待ち受けるだけであるため、ある程度、汎用性を無視した受信専用モジュールで十分です。
そのため、標準ライブラリで、何となく動くものを作成しました。

websokectsモジュールやasyncioで接続したセッションに対して、socketインスタンスに移譲してsetsockoptメソッドが使用できれば良いのですが、、、どなたか方法をご存知の方は、別途回答をいただきたいと思います。

```py
from base64 import encodebytes as base64encode
import os
import selectors
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time
import traceback
import urllib.parse

class ClientWebSocket(object):
    def __init__(self, url:str,
        on_open=None, on_recv_msg=None, on_err_msg=None, on_close=None
        ):

        self.url=url

        # callback method
        self.on_open=on_open
        self.on_recv_msg=on_recv_msg
        self.on_err_msg=on_err_msg
        self.on_close=on_close

        return

    def _callback_method_(self,method,*args):
        if method:
            try:
                method(self,*args)
            except Exception as err:
                if self.on_err_msg:
                    self.on_err_msg(self,err)
        return

    def run(self):
        try:
            url = urllib.parse.urlsplit(self.url)
        except Exception as err:
            if self.on_err_msg:
                self.on_err_msg(self,err)
            return err

        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(
                family=socket.AF_INET,type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.connect((url.hostname,url.port))
            self._keep_alive_(self.sock)

            self._callback_method_(self.on_open)

            send_msg = self._create_web_socket_msg_(url.hostname,url.port,url.path)

            self.sock.sendall(send_msg.encode())

            self._read_()

        except Exception as err:
            if self.on_err_msg:
                self.on_err_msg(self,err)
            return err

    def _keep_alive_(self,sock):
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE,1)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE,30)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL,30)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT,5)

    def _read_(self):
        while True:
            select = selectors.DefaultSelector()
            select.register(self.sock,selectors.EVENT_READ)

            read = select.select()
            if read:
                msg = self.sock.recv(1024)
                if self.on_recv_msg:
                    self.on_recv_msg(msg)

            select.close()

    def _create_web_socket_msg_(self,hostname,port,path):

        sec_key = self._create_sec_websocket_key()

        msg = f'GET {path} HTTP/1.1\r\n'
        msg += f'Upgrade: websocket\r\n'
        msg += f'HOST: {hostname}:{port}\r\n'
        msg += f'Origin: http://{hostname}:{port}\r\n'
        msg += f'Sec-WebSocket-Key: {sec_key}\r\n'
        msg += f'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n'
        msg += f'Connection: Upgrade\r\n\r\n'

        return msg


    def _create_sec_websocket_key(self):
        return base64encode(os.urandom(16)).decode('utf-8').strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def on_open(*args):
        return

    def on_msg(*args):
        print(args)
        return

    def on_error(*args):
        return

    def on_close(*args):
        return

    instSock = ClientWebSocket(
        url = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/path',
        on_open=on_open,
        on_recv_msg=on_msg,
        on_err_msg=on_error,
        on_close=on_close
        )
    instSock.run()
```

Comment: このコードは不完全です。実装するためにはいろいろと肉付けする必要があります。